# Comibe Multiples Excel Tables

Tags: excel

I have multiple Tables/sheets with Total Row in a workbook۔ I want to combine tables from sheets 1 to 10 (which may grow) without Total Row into an excel table. The resulting combine table should include a total amount row in Combine Sheet.

[image: Excel sheet]

Comment: If you have ***Microsoft-365*** then could try `=VSTACK('1:10'!A2:D11)` to combine tables data without total row.

Comment: No Sir i use office LTSC

Comment: What did you try?

Comment: Dominique Thanks for your intrest.  I have  a VBA code to an another workbook but it is not giving the desired results.    It has to be run repeatedly:-

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

lDestRows).Resize(lSourceRows)

```
                    'Resize the destination table
                    loDest.Resize loDest.Range.Resize(1 + lSourceRows + lDestRows)

                    For Each lc In .ListColumns
                     Intersect(loDest.ListColumns(lc.Name).Range.EntireColumn, rDest).Value2 = lc.DataBodyRange.Value
                    Next lc
                    Set lc = Nothing
                    On Error Resume Next
                    Set lc = .ListColumns(lcSource.Name)
                    On Error GoTo 0
                    If lc Is Nothing Then Intersect(lcSource.Range, rDest.EntireRow).Value2 = ws.Name
                End If
            End If
        End With
    End If
Next lo
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: Thanks a lot sir – Community Bot  
For the reminder, I have found the solution.